# org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.ConnectorImpI$StringArgumentImpI.<int>(Lorg/eclipse/jdi

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

So I code minecraft mods in java on visual studio code, but yesterday I started getting an error when I try to launch the game and debug it.

The error is "`org.exlipse.jdi.internal.connect.ConnectorImpI$StringArgumentImpI.<int>(Lorg/eclipse/jdi...`"

I have tried reinstalling vscode, reinstall all the mod assests but its not working. Here is my code :

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Minecraft Client",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/run",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "mainClass": "net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main",
      "vmArgs": "-Dfabric.dli.config\u003dE:\\Documents\\Ruby\\.gradle\\loom-cache\\launch.cfg -Dfabric.dli.env\u003dclient -Dfabric.dli.main\u003dnet.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient",
      "args": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Minecraft Server",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/run",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "mainClass": "net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main",
      "vmArgs": "-Dfabric.dli.config\u003dE:\\Documents\\Ruby\\.gradle\\loom-cache\\launch.cfg -Dfabric.dli.env\u003dserver -Dfabric.dli.main\u003dnet.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotServer",
      "args": "nogui"
    }
  ]
}
```

If there is someone who knows how to fix this error then it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8RZa.png

Answer (score 1):

The question you've encountered is already put in github, please view [After upgrade from vscode-java v0.77.0 to v0.78.0 can't debug tests](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/995)

So, the workaround is downgrading **JavaLanguage Support for Java by Red Hat** version to 0.77.0. Please refer to [Detailed steps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/995#issuecomment-829884260).

Update: the bug is fixed by engineers, release 0.33.1 for **Debugger for Java** extension. It will work with both vscode-java@0.77.0 and 0.78.0. Please have a try.

Comment: Actually that isn't really true, what you had to do is re-install the plugin "Visual Studio IntelliCode" and then everything would work fine